# Before the Colossus and the ENIAC, did ever an electronic calculator exist?

Tags: computers

I've done some searching on the internet, and I found that an electronic analog computer was built in 1942 in Germany, during World War II. But, before the first electronic computer, weren't there electronic calculators, which are simpler machines? Was that German electronic computer a revolutionary creation?
That's all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the [Atanasoff-Berry computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_computer) qualify under your criteria?

Comment: Konrad Zuse's Z3 was built in 1941, and was a fully programmable digital computer, but can't be considered 'electronic', since it used electromechanical relays. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)

Comment: If you think of simple calculators (i.e. not programmable), mechanical calculators are easy and cheap. On the other hand, transistors were only really available after the war, so any electronics was complicated and expensive and there wasn't really an advantage over mechanical calculators. Only when you want more complex machines like programmable computers, electronics has advantages over mechanics.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your comments; they are interesting I have taken them into account.